# javascript if statement to do-while

Tags: javascript, do-while

I am trying to get this snip of code to work in a while loop instead of an if.
I need each instant of num_# to not be displayed if the printLoad_# val is empty. So if printLoad_1 value = nothing, the Num_1 would not be displayed, and then the printLoad_2 would check to see if its num_2 is empty and so on.
The problem I am having is the function stops before checking each section.
Im not sure if a do-while will work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(document.getElementById("printLoad_1").value == "")
    {
        document.getElementById('num_1').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementById("printLoad_2").value == "")
    {
        document.getElementById('num_2').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementById("printLoad_3").value == "")
    {
        document.getElementById('num_3').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementById("printLoad_4").value == "")
    {
        document.getElementById('num_4').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementById("printLoad_5").value == "")
    {
        document.getElementById('num_5').style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Comment: Is your question "how do I use a while loop" or is it "what's wrong with my code"?

Comment: its a bit of both, sorry

Comment: well, do you get any errors?

Comment: Diagnosis: seems like a case of _iditis_. Use common classes, and target elements by index, it'll be much simpler.

Comment: iditis? More like inexperience. Thanks anyways...

Comment: Are you using jQuery or not? You could do it in a couple lines...

Comment: The only way this function will "stop" is if there is an error - such as getElementById evaluating to null which is then used as receiver. If there is an error it will be reported in the Error Console. That being said; definitely use a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered just compositing the strings instead of this verbose construction?  Something like this:

```
for( var i=1; i<=5; i++ ) {
  if( document.getElementById('printLoad_'+i).value === '' ) {
      document.getElementById('num_'+i).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: This actually works for the inputs, but I am having trouble getting this to work dynamically. I will use what you have given me and try to come up with another question that builds off this one. Thanks!

Comment: @user2089255 If by dynamic you mean a variable amount of inputs then look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using jQuery and that your elements are in order, I'd forget about ID's. If you use common classes, say `.printload` and `.num`, then you can easily target elements by index like:

```
$('.printload').each(function(i){
  if (!this.value) $('.num').eq(i).hide();
});
```

Comment: @user2089255  note that printLoad and num is the class of the element.

Comment: Yes. When using jQuery, anytime you see the id="*_#" type constructs, you can almost always do this better using classes instead of (or in addition to) id's.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a variable amount of printLoad and num:

```
var i = 1,
pl=document.getElementById('printLoad_'+i),
num = document.getElementById('num_'+i);
while(pl !== null && num !== null){
  if(pl.value === ""){
    num.style.display = 'none';
  }
  i++;
  pl=document.getElementById('printLoad_'+i),
  num = document.getElementById('num_'+i);
}
```

Comment: Well this works too, same problem I am having with other working script. I think I have my code in an incorrect place. Ill move things around and see.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight modification of Ethan's answer that "works dynamically". I've also updated it to use jQuery. This could be handled cleaner if *CSS classes* and a *hierarchy relationship* were used, but that would affect how the DOM needed to be generated ..

```
for (var i = 1; /* break */; i++) {
    var printEl = $('#printLoad_' + i)
    if (printEl.length) {
        if (!printEl.val()) {
            $('#num_' + i).css({display: 'none'})
        }
    } else {
        // No #printLoad_N, guess we're done looking
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per @elclanr 's answer:

> Use common classes, and target elements by index, it'll be much simpler.

Set your "printLoad" elements to `class='printLoad'` and your "num" elements to `class='num'`. Then...

```
for (i=0;i<document.getElementByClass('printLoad').length;i++)
{
    if (document.getElementByClass('printLoad')[i].value == "")
    {
        document.getElementByClass('num')[i].style.display='none';
    }
}
```